# What does this 'Led' or 'Σed' indication mean?

Tags: piano, notation

In Mark Levine's *The Jazz Theory Book*, there is this example to be played on the piano:

*The Jazz Theory Book*, figure 3-149
[image: The Jazz Theory Book, figure 3-149]

I've never had any piano training/lessons, so I don't really know the indications.

What does 'Led' (or is it 'Σed') mean?

Comment: `Ped.` for [pedale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_musical_terminology#P).

Comment: Interesting that the notes written Eb are accompanied by a G7#5 chord. Should they be a D#?

Comment: @Tim Seeing as the E♭ resolves down to D, I'd say that E♭ is correctly spelt, and that the chord symbol is wrong. I'd analyse it as G ♭13. The G root resolves to C, so it may fairly be taken as a dominant chord. F is there, so, dominant 7th. The E♭ is above the 7th and may thus be analysed as the 13th.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the pedal sign look like “Leo”?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111755/why-does-the-pedal-sign-look-like-leo)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's actually **Ped**, and just instructs the pianist to use the **sustain pedal**, in this   section.

Answer (score 11):

It means to use hold down the damper pedal until the end of the dash. The effect is that every note you play while the pedal is held down is sustained.

There are actually a few variations of this notation with another popular form of it [shown here](http://piano.about.com/od/musicaltermssymbols/ss/2Int_SheetMusic_7.htm). The idea behind the other common form is to show where you press the pedal (the PED) and where you release the pedal (the *).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pedale marking, and there is even a Unicode encoding for it, U+1D1AE, see [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/1D1AE/):

Or copied in (unfortunately very small):

> 

Comment: FYI: the copied, quoted character does not display properly (on macOS Monterey).

Answer (score 1):

It actually means "Ped" for pedale. The pedale symbol directs you to step on the pedal. If you see an asterisk beside it, it indicates that you should release the pedal.
[image] So you should stop using the pedal after the asterisk. I hope this helps.

Comment: See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111755/why-does-the-pedal-sign-look-like-leo