# How to notate lack of pedal for a measure?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music, keyboard-pedals

I'm writing a piano piece, for most of which I would like to use a blanket *con pedale* instead of marking pedals for each measure. However, at exactly one point, there are two nonconsecutive measures which should *not* be sustained, like this:

[image: A segment of a grand staff showing three complete measures of music. The second one and the incomplete measures on either side are marked with explicit Ped/* notation, while the first and third have no pedaling and their notes are marked staccatissimo.]

What is the proper way to notate the *absence* of pedal for these two measures, while still making clear that all the surrounding material should be pedaled at the player's discretion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first non-pedaled measure can be marked *senza ped.*, the next measure can use either a standard pedal indication as in the question image or *con ped.*, and then another *senza ped.* for the other non-pedaled measure. After that, *con ped.* will serve.

Comment: I would have no problem, if the weird "Leò" marking was changed to whatever font is actually understandable these days, and if the texts were _with pedal_ and _without pedal_ instead of something in Italian. :)

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica If you've not already seen it, you might be interested in [Why does the pedal sign look like “Leo”?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/111755/70803).

Comment: That's where I got the "Leò" idea from. If it was written with a contemporary commonly understood font, nothing of value would be lost.

Comment: The indication *secco* ("dry") in piano music means staccato, but usually entails using no pedal.