# Alkan Prelude in A-flat minor Op 31 No 8 - how properly use sostenuto pedal in this piece?

Tags: technique, keyboard-pedals

[Link to the score](https://musescore.com/user/8289536/scores/1982871)

This is the first piece I've attempted that calls for sostenuto pedal rather than sustain pedal throughout (assuming I'm interpreting the notation correctly). Other than **sempre Ped.** in bar 28, the only pedal notation is **Led sostenuto** in bar 1 and **Pedale sempre molto sostenuto** in bar 4, all of which adds up to sostenuto instead of sustain throughout I think.

[image: Alkan Op. 31, No. 8, mm. 1–3]

How do I properly use the sostenuto pedal then? I'm thinking play the first bass chord in each measure, then hit the sostenuto pedal, then release after last bass chord in each measure. Is that correct?

Comment: That 'Led' is 'Ped'! Not even sure it means the sostenuto *pedal*. Sostenuto means sustained, and that can be done using the damper pedal

Comment: But it reads 'Led sostenuto'. Doesn't that translate to Sostenuto pedal? You're correct of course that the literal meaning of sostenuto is sustain, but surely there's a distinction between the sostenuto and sustain pedal?

Comment: This Musescore notation looks poorly formatted; I recommend confirming the notation in IMSLP.

Comment: I did confirm the notation in IMSLP before I posted. I thought the fragment I posted was a little more legible.

Comment: I finally found a video showing feet! If this is being played correctly, then Tim is correct. Clearly the sustain pedal is being used. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P72m_7R4UwM

Comment: It still doesn't read 'Led' - it reads '**P**ed. Look at the typeface. If it was the same for both words, it *might* make sense. But it's not. And using the sostenuto pedal isn't particularly useful for what music I can see.

Comment: Regarding "Led", see [Why does the pedal sign look like “Leo”?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/111755/70803).

Comment: Another related "Led" question: [What does this 'Led' or 'Σed' indication mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/30539/70803).

Comment: It reads Led in the excerpt, but Ped on IMSLP. Lesson learned: quote from IMSLP. Thanks! https://imslp.org/wiki/25_Preludes%2C_Op.31_(Alkan%2C_Charles-Valentin)

Comment: Which bit do you think says "Led"? It's definitely not this bit - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtiGb.png - that's the absolute standard font/symbol used for "Ped" & has been since Elgar was in shorts.

Comment: Even if it did read Led - what would that mean to anyone?

Comment: Keyboard lights up ;) …or, You can lead a horse to water, but a Zeppelin must be Led.

Comment: @Tetsujin I get that I shouldn't have read and written it as Led. It just looks like Led to me, I always thought it was equivalent to Ped. My mistake.

Comment: @Tetsujin - you can lead a horse to water, but a pencil must be lead...

Comment: In any case *sostenuto* and 'sustain' mean the same thing. Your question is based on a  false dichotomy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four separate instructions:

1. Ped.
2. Sostenuto
3. Pedale sempre
4. molto sostenuto

"Sostenuto" here means "sustained" and refers to the overall sound, not to the pedal used. The piece uses the sustain pedal. The specific timing of the pedal depends on the sound the performer wants to achieve.

The minimum amount of pedal would be to change the pedal each time there's a new chord. In the excerpt shown in the OP, once per measure would be fine. Elsewhere, the piece would require twice per measure.

More pedal would be used for a "cleaner", but still *sostenuto* (sustained) sound. For example, one can pedal at the beginning of m. 2, but then again in m. 2 when the RH E flat occurs. That allows for a legato, warm sound, but without the RH B flat carrying across into the E flat. In the next measure, in addition to changing the pedal at the first chord, one could also change the pedal on the second LH chord, depending on how literally the rests are interpreted (as RH silence, or as RH fading away).

Comment: I suppose I would lean toward changing pedal at the beginning of each new chord. My reasoning is the instructions 'Pedale sempre' and 'molto sustenuto', which I take together to mean keep the pedal down (of course that's just my take). I also assume 'sempre' means throughout the piece. Although I do wonder why Alkan felt it necessary to write 'sempre Ped.' at bar 28. That could mean I'm wrong about his intention to lean towards keeping the pedal down. By keeping pedal down I mean only change when a chord changes.

Comment: @markmarz I agree that your interpretation is a reasonable one. And your observation about m. 28 is quite interesting! To add to it: why in m. 3 does he use "Pedale sempre" and in m. 28 "sempre Ped.' (i.e., words reversed). Did he intend different meanings? For example, m. 3 = "Use the pedal consistently throughout the piece" vs. m. 28 = "Don't change the pedal during these next few measures."

Comment: I wish I knew! But thank you for your interesting and thoughtful interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer - read my comments! No particular sostenuto pedalling is needed - or asked for. Play smoothly - and use the damper pedal to help that.

Comment: I did read your comments, thank you! I also replied to them twice.

Comment: This is for you - and anyone reading in the future...